# Scaling the data still gives NaN in python

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis, bigdata

The problem is that after removing all the columns in my data with equal values on the rows and applying the formula for max-min scaling which is: (x-x.min())/(x.max()-x.min()) I still got a column with NaNs.

P.S. I removed these constant columns because if I keep them and then do the scaling, x.max()-x.min() will be 0 and all these columns after the scaling will have NaN values.

So, what I am doing is the following:

I have train and test data sets separately. Once I import them in jupyter notebook, I create a function to show me which columns have exactly the same values on the rows.

```
def uniques(df):
    for e in df.columns:
        if len(pd.unique(df[e]))==1:
            yield e
```

Then I check which are the constant columns:

```
col_test_=uniques(test_st1)
col_test=list(col_test_)
col_test
```

Result:

```
['uswrf_s1_3','uswrf_s1_6','uswrf_s1_10','uswrf_s1_11','uswrf_s1_13','uswrf_s1_5']
```

Then I get all indices of these columns:

```
 for i in list(col_test):
     idx_col=test_st1.columns.get_loc(i)
     print ("All values in column {} of the test data are the same".format(idx_col))
```

Result:

```
All values in column 220 of the test data are the same
All values in column 445 of the test data are the same
All values in column 745 of the test data are the same
All values in column 820 of the test data are the same
All values in column 970 of the test data are the same
All values in column 1120 of the test data are the same
```

Then I drop these columns because I would not need them after I apply the min- max scaling.

```
for j in col_test:
    test_st1=test_st1.drop(j,1)
```

Basically I do the same for the train partition. 
Next I apply the formula for max min scaling to both train and test partitions with respect to the train data:

```
train_1= (train_st1-train_st1.min())/(train_st1.max()-train_st1.min())
test_1 = (test_st1-train_st1.min())/(train_st1.max()-train_st1.min())
```

After I got rid of the columns with the same values I supposed that there won't be any columns with NaNs after the normalization. However, when I check if there is any column with NaN values then the following happens:

```
a=uniques(test_1)
b=list(a)
b
```

Result:

```
['uswrf_s1_3']
```

Checking which column is that:

```
test_1.columns.get_loc('uswrf_s1_3')
```

Result:

```
1126
```

How come I got a column with NaNs after the scaling bearing in mind that I got rid of all the columns whose values on the rows are completely the same?

Comment: Scaling is different from imputing.

Comment: Yes. I don't want to make any imputations. I am just not sure why after I scaled the data I still got a column with NaNs. Initially I removed all the constant columns that otherwise would have caused me a trouble.

Comment: Provide sample data that reproduces the phenomenon. In general, you should always provide a [mcve].